# wampserver installation not opening

Tags: windows, operating-system

please can someone assist I have some applications that I have recently downloaded - wampserver and vc++ redistributables. Each time I try run the installation files nothing happens. I am on windows 10 not sure if it might be some security setting.

Answer (score 0):

program compatibility issues with windows 10, ran test compatibility function by right clicking on the installer icon.